# Using random_shuffle causes SIGSEGV or SIGBUS

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk

This call on Android NDK

```
random_shuffle(node->elements.front(), node->elements.back());
```

causes a SIGBUS or SIGSEGV.
I'm using gnustl (shared/static makes no difference).
Also, I can't switch stl libraries because I need exception support.
So far all other stl functions work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `node->elements.begin()` and `node->elements.end()`.

`front()` and `back()` return elements, not iterators. I presume that `node->elements` is a collection of pointers; in that case, `random_shuffle` will try to randomize whatever's in memory between the address of the first element and the address of the last element. This is not what you want.

Comment: @user829996, if it solved your problem, consider clicking the check mark besides this answer. It tells your question has been answered.